# Firebase Realtime Database streaming not working in C# application

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm writing an application in C#.

I installed the package FirebaseDatabase.net (https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet).

And I'm able to query data from the Firebase Realtime Database, but the streaming update is not working.

Below a piece of my code:

```cs
    internal class DataSource
    {
        private FirebaseClient firebase;
        private static string pathRef;
        private IDisposable observable;

        public DataSource()
        {
            firebase = new FirebaseClient("https://xxx.firebaseio.com/");
            pathRef = "panorama_rt";

            observable = firebase
                .Child(pathRef)
                .AsObservable<Quote>()
                .Subscribe(e =>
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Key);
                });
        }
        private async Task<Quote> GetQuoteAsync(string symbol)
        {
            try
            {
                var _quote = await firebase
                    .Child(pathRef)
                    .Child(symbol)
                    .OnceSingleAsync<Quote>();

                if (_quote == null)
                    return null;

                return _quote;
            } 
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

The function GetQuoteAsync works fine to query data.

But I need to subscribe to receive data on each update on the Firebase.

My observable is not working. I'm not getting any error on subscribe but not getting any update as well.

Is there any bug in my code ? How to fix it to get the data updates ?

Comment: Can you make sure data at path ```panorama_rt/``` is being updated in the Realtime Database by logging into the Firebase console and verifying that the data is changing?

Comment: You need to save (see link) for updates to work.  You are performing a query and the query is not getting any results.  The "StartAt" in link you are calling in your code pathRef.  The link is not showing a forward slash while your code has the slash.  You also are not setting the property "StartAt".

Comment: @esQmo_ yes. I have the Firebase console opened and I can see the data being update.

Comment: @jdweng I didn't understand very well what you said. But the query data (GetQuoteAsync) is working. The problema is the .Subscribe. I believe that pathRef is correct because the GetQuoteAsync is working using it. Can you provide some code showing what you are saying ?

Comment: @esQmo_ the function below in JS works using the same configuration.
function readData() {
                var ref = database.ref('panorama_rt');
    
                ref.on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
                    displayData('child_added', snapshot.key, snapshot.val());
                });
    
                ref.on('child_changed', function (snapshot) {
                    displayData('child_changed', snapshot.key, snapshot.val());
                });
            }

Comment: Okay, can you try adding error handling to your subscription by using the Subscribe method’s overload that takes an ```OnError``` delegate? This will allow you to see if any errors are occurring when attempting to receive updates. ```.Subscribe(
        e => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Key),
        ex => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}")
    );```

Comment: @esQmo_ no error using the OnError as you said.

Comment: @esQmo_ I'm writting a COM .ddl to implement a RTD server. My project type is a class library. do you think that this might be the cause of the problem ?

Comment: I doubt so (but I can be wrong, I'm not an expert). I guess this is a common way to implement a RTD server. Just make sure you have properly registered COM dll on the system where you're trying to use it

Comment: @esQmo_ yes, ny COM dll it's correct because I' using it on the Excel with success. I need get the firebase update now to update the excel.

Comment: Path is good if you are getting results.  You need to save any changes with either PostAsync or PutAsync.

Comment: @jdweng there is another application (python) that is saving/changing data on firebase. in this c# one I just need get updated values (read only). may you provide some code If I'm not getting your point, please ?

Comment: If another app is saving the data and you are not getting the updates then something is wrong with the connection string.  You must have two different databases and the saving is done to a different database.  Usually in these cases the connection string is different in firebase and in the c# application.